# MacOS: zsh: command not found: sdk after adding android sdk to path

Tags: android, macos, path, zsh

I'm following some tutorials of setting up android sdk in MacOS command line, and no matter what I tried it doesn't seems to add the commands `android` or `sdk` to the path

I already have the following in my `~/.zshrc`

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
```

I also tried `export ANDROID_HOME="~/Library/Android/sdk` as the first line or `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`, but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated

I've tried editing the `~/.zshrc` file in various way, yet the command `sdk` or `android` still isn't in the PATH as the tutorials suggested

Comment: sdk & android are not commands. Adding the platform-tools is usually done to have the "adb" command. And adding the ANDROID_HOME is done for the system (gradle, Android Studio, etc..) to know where your Android SDK is located.

Comment: Weird, both of the tutorials I saw use `sdk` as the command, I guess I'll look it up, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i've been facing the same problem, and somehow this solved the issue for me:

Run `sudo export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/YOU_USER_NAME/Library/Android/sdk`

Then `export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/YOU_USER_NAME/Library/Android/sdk`

and finally  `echo $ANDROID_HOME` to check.
Also make sure to restart your IDE before retrying

This solved the issue for my case and ANDROID_HOME set successfully, i hope this work for you.
GOOD LUCK